# Creating a user 'add custom field' section

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, custom-field, javascript

I'm trying to make this plugin where users can add a custom attribute for something i working  on:

So far what i've done is:

[image]

which uses this code here:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

function elements()
{
    var element = document.getElementById("addnew");   
    var table = document.getElementById("newData");

    element.onclick = function(){


        var row = table.insertRow(table.lastChild);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        var t1= document.createElement("input");
                        t1.id = "dl-attribute";
                        cell.appendChild(t1);        
        var t2= document.createElement("input");
                        t2.id = "dl-value";
                        cell.appendChild(t2);
                        var btn = document.createElement("input");     
                        btn.type = "button";
                        btn.value = "Apply";
                        btn.id = "apply";
                        cell.appendChild(btn); 

        var apply = document.getElementById("apply");
        apply.onclick = function()
        {
            t2.name = "dlm_options["+t1.value+"]";
        }
    }
}


    elements();


}, false);
```

However whenever i click save settings the field which are created are not shown when the page refreshes.

Personally i think i'm going about this the wrong way.

can anybody shed some light into this situation and point me in the right direction?

Regards!

Comment: Where is the code that saves the form to the database?

Comment: Well i;ve noticed that the options themselves are actually saved, however it's just the actual fields are not.

Comment: And after reading your comment, the actual fields themselves are not saved. I have no idea as to how to go about that.

Comment: Search the site for "save_post"